# Getting error (The thread 0x2884 has exited with code 259 (0x103)) with IIS Express using .NET EventLog

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I’m getting a kind of weird error on my application (The thread 0x2884 has exited with code 259 (0x103)) but first, I’m going to explain what exactly am doing. I’m trying to program an event handler following this post from Microsoft (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440729(v=pandp.60).aspx#CreatinganEventSource) so I make my own custom class to manage the events. Adding the sample code from these tutorials was simple but when i run my application, to understand how exactly works, I got a lot of this error’s in my application (The thread 0x2884 has exited with code 259 (0x103) (1), in addition, this is the code what I ran (2). If you guys find the error or I’m doing something wrong with the configuration of IIS please let me know. Thank you.

(1) IIS - Error

'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/38/ROOT-1-130905233982905410): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.HtmlParser\v4.0_12.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.HtmlParser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x2884 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x27d0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x32f8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x5f0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x2e1c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x828 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x32b4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xb78 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[12604] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12604] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

(2) Code -

```
public void testWriterLog()
{
            TextFormatter formatter = new TextFormatter("Timestamp: ... ");

            var rollingFlatFileTraceListener =
            new RollingFlatFileTraceListener(@"C:\Users\hkcastro\Documents\Logs\RollingFlatFile.log",
                                              "----------------------------------------",
                                              "----------------------------------------",
                                              formatter, 20, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                              RollFileExistsBehavior.Increment, RollInterval.None, 3);

            var eventLog = new EventLog("Application", ".", "Enterprise Library Logging");
            var eventLogTraceListener = new FormattedEventLogTraceListener(eventLog);
            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
            config.AddLogSource("General", SourceLevels.All, true).AddTraceListener(eventLogTraceListener);
            config.AddLogSource("Important", SourceLevels.All, true).AddTraceListener(eventLogTraceListener);
            config.LogSources["Important"].AddTraceListener(rollingFlatFileTraceListener);

            LogWriter logWriter = new LogWriter(config);
        }
```

Comment: Threads can exit with any code, but the process exits with 0 which means no error. What exactly is the problem you met?

Comment: Hi  lex Li, im trying to track all events from my application using enterprise library 6 of Microsoft, using this topic (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440729(v=pandp.60).aspx) but unfortunately the samples showed doesn’t work fine for me and I don’t know why, I have to use the System.Diagnostics.EventLog for an alternative to register the events generated by the user in the application.